# 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'sparkSession' when creating dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, spyder

I am working with Pyspark in Spyder Python IDE, and I am trying to execute the next code fragment:

```
prueba_2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(...)
```

But when I run it, I get the next error:

```
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'sparkSession'
```

I also have the next code fragments:

```
conf=SparkConf()

conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

conf.set("spark.cores.max", "2")

conf.setAppName("name")
sc = SparkContext('local', conf=conf) 

spark = SparkSession\
 .builder\
 .appName("name")\
 .getOrCreate()
```

What is happening? How an I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use both `SparkContext` and `SparkSession` to initialize Spark. Since `SparkSession` is the newer, recommended way, use that:

```
spark = SparkSession\
  .builder\
  .config("spark.executor.memory"，"1g")\
  .config("spark.cores.max"，"2")\
  .appName("name")\
  .getOrCreate()
```

`createDataFrame` can then be accessed by:

```
prueba_2 = spark.createDataFrame(...)
```

If you have to use the underlying `SparkContext`, you can simply do `spark.sparkContext`.

Comment: I did it, but when I want to execute other methods like "sc.textFile(path)", as I don't have a 'sc' object (SparkContext object), if I try to run "spark.textFile(path)" I get the error: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'textFile'.

Comment: @jartymcfly Added more information regarding this in the last part of the answer.